# Destructuring function results in truffle console

Tags: truffle

I want to do something individually with the BigNumbers that are returned here, but I am having trouble assigning them to variables.

```
truffle(develop)> reg.getProviderCurve(addr,spec)
[ BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 1 ] },
  BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 1 ] },
  BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 2 ] } ]
truffle(develop)> [n,m,p] = reg.getProviderCurve(addr,spec)
TypeError: reg.getProviderCurve is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to do, the default truffle syntax has [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html) included, and there you can replace

`.then(...)` with

```
.spread(function(bigNumber1, bigNumber2){

   someVar = bigNumber1.toString();
   someOtherVar = bigNumber2.toNumber();
})
```

if a contract has multiple return values. If you are just playing around with BigNumber objects, it might be that you need to instantiate n,m and p as BigNumber objects first.